# Android - Unable to instantiate cardview

Tags: android, xml

The following is the stack trace I got when I used CardView support library

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/cardview/R$color
    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:227)
    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:178)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$58(RenderTask.java:659)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:380)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.inflate(RenderTask.java:659)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.inflate(NlModel.java:327)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.updateModel(NlModel.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel$1.run(NlModel.java:237)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:267)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:282)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

this happened when I created a CardView for a scrollview inside a Linear Layout. Here is the xml for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.ListActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

can somebody explain the cause of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse than just import the v7 compact library project into your work space and add it as a library to your project else if you are doing it from terminal than what you can do is put `android-support-v7-appcompat` library project (which you can find in `sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`)in the same directory where is your project and add this line to your `project.properties` file

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

do not forget to add both the jar files v4,v7 to your project as well.

Comment: support.v7.appcompat is already there in both my external libraries as well as project folder.. apart from this my build.gradle file has also the dependancy for support.v7-appcompat and support.v7.cardview-23.4.0

Comment: @AnirudhSrivastav after adding dependencies try cleaning and re-building your project.

Comment: @AnirudhSrivastav are you changing cardView's color programatically ?

Comment: no i simply created one cardview which will later be populated into multiple cardviews in form of a list with server side functions. In order to do that i need an existing cardview inside my activity so that it can trace the action of the previous activity. I havent added any attributes as of yet